# Ruby updating partial with a map: You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, haml

I have a HAML file that renders partial that contains map
show.html.haml:

```
      .row
        .col-xs-12
          .panel-group(style="margin-bottom: 0")
            .stat-panel(style="padding: 5px; height:88.89px; margin:0")
              .stat-cell.bg.col-md-1.col-sm-3.col-xs-3
                %i.fa.fa-map-marker.bg-icon.bg-icon-left{:style => "font-size:60px;line-height:80px;height:80px;"}
              .stat-cell.bg.valign-middle(style="padding-left: 40px;")
                Geographic Summary
            .panel.no-border.no-padding
              = render partial: 'map_content', locals: {demographics: @demographics, listicle: @listicle}
```

And that partial _map_content.html.haml contains map:

```
    .panel-body.no-border.no-padding{:style => "position:relative;height: 600px;"}
      #map-container.widget-maps
        /%script{:src => "assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"}
        /%script{:src => "assets/javascripts/pixel-admin.min.js"}
        /%script{:src => "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"}
        /%script{:src => "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"}
        /%script{:src => "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"}
        :javascript
          var map;
          var markers=[];
          var coord = #{@coordinates};
          var la = #{@current_lat};
          var lo = #{@current_long};
          function setMarkers(locations, lat, lon) {
                  if (coord.length !=0){
                  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                      var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]);
                      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                               position: myLatLng,
                               map: map,
                               animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                      });
                      markers.push(marker);
                  }}
                      var curLatLong =  new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
                      var current_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                               position: curLatLong,
                               map: map,
                               animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                               title: 'You are here'
                      });
                      markers.push(current_marker);
          }

      function reloadMarkers() {
               for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
                   markers[i].setMap(null);
               }
               markers = [];
               setMarkers(coord, la, lo);
      }


      function init_map() {
              var var_mapoptions = {
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.5202922,-96.2318707),
                zoom: 5
              }
              map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-container"),
                   var_mapoptions);

              setMarkers(coord, la, lo);

              var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
              document.getElementById('q-itm').addEventListener('click', reloadMarkers);
      }
    %script{:src=>"http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"}

    %script{:src => "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCi93_Ajfvl-ZwxPRwqVI98hcqfu2LF3Ic&callback=init_map"}
    :cdata
```

The logic is:
the show.haml has another partial, that has Submit button. After a user enters info in that partial and clicks Submit, only the maps_content partial gets updated (not the whole page). However, I'm getting this error in console (though, everything works fine and I'm just afraid of possible run times errors if someone maybe will click on submit many times):
**You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.**

I understand that this happens because src=>... gets loaded multiple times in the same DIV, after Submit is clicked. 
I tried to move src=> upper, to the show file. But then the map would load on the whole page refresh only, but when I would click Submit, it won't load and DIV stands white without a map.

Any suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have been involved in writing a small gem to handle this type of issues:

https://github.com/trialbee/assets_ledger

The basic idea is that your partials register their dependencies in a "ledger" and then the layout asks the ledger what dependencies it should include. And it is up to the ledger to make sure that all dependencies only are included once.

(The easiest version of this is a globally accessible hash)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!